# How can I redirect an existing ASP.NET MVC route to another (using HTTP 301)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Company",
        "{id}/{name}.aspx",
        new { controller = "Company", action = "CompanyIndex" }
        );
```

I need redirect to the same URL, but without ".aspx" extension:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Company",
        "{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Company", action = "CompanyIndex" }
        );
```

But the old URL (with aspx extension) can't return 404 error code. It just need redirect using 301 permanent redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a redirection handler. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119055309/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2009/05/19/132204.aspx)